# Error while login in Ubuntu using Fingerprint GUI

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, fingerprint-reader

When I am trying to login in Ubuntu using Fingerprint GUI I receive the following error :

```
ERROR: FOUND ENCRYPTED HOMEDIR BUT NO PASSWORD
```

I have installed my fingerprint for both `sudo` and `su` operations but the problem keeps persisting.

Does anyone know if this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue with 14.04 and encrypted home folder.

## Solution

You should use the last tab of Fingerprint UI ("Password") to store your encrypted password on a removable device. You'll need to insert the removable USB stick for every first login after reboot or shutdown. Then, as long as you have active user session you can use just the fingerprint to get back to that session, for example, after closing and opening the lid.

If you don't have the media inserted at the first login, you have to type your password. After that, it'll work as usual, without the media.

## Technical Details

It seems that your password is used as the key to encrypt your home folder. That means, that it is impossible to mount the home volume without the password. Fingerprint recognition subsystem in Ubuntu stores your password on a removable media to be able to decrypt the volume on first login. It encrypts the password file itself with fingerprint checksum or hash.

Comment: Does this work even if the password of the encrypted home folder is different from the one that it is being used to login?I am asking because I did what the Solution describes and it for a few seconds the screen shows a black screen with some things that I am not able to read because it immediately redirects me back to the login screen.

Comment: Disappointing that I have to have a flash drive to use my fingerprint for the first login upon reboot/shutdown, but thank you for this helpful information.